# Resolve Subdomains to Full Domains

Tags: dns

I'm trying to work out how I could configure my machine (presumably my machine's DNS settings) to resolve subdomains to the appropriate full domain of my site, mostly for shorthand purposes in development. For example, I would like 'www' to resolve to 'www.mysite.com', 'blah' to 'blah.mysite.com' and so on.

I don't really know where to start other than that I'm pretty sure this is outside the remit of simple /etc/hosts shenanigans. Will I need to run a local DNS server?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add mysite.com to the search domains. In your resolv.conf (assuming you are using *NIX), add the following

```
search mysite.com local.lan
nameserver <ip>
nameserver <ip>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for :) DNS config noob...